# Trying to run GAE python - not sure if imports and app.yaml is configured correctly

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy the following python code named image-getter.py in GAE:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import os
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

#the addimage endpoint
class AddImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        image = self.request.get('image')
        i = Image()
        i.picture = db.Blob(image)
        i.put()
        self.response.out.write('done');

#the Image object: 
class Image(db.Model):
    picture = db.BlobProperty();

#to get the image  : /getimage?key=sdfsadfsf...
class GetImage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        images_query = Image.get(self.request.get('key'))
        if (images_query and images_query.picture):
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/jpeg"
            self.response.out.write(images_query.picture)

#to draw the images out to the main page: 
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        images = db.Query(Image)
        keys = [];
        for image in images:
            keys.append(str(image.key()))

        template_values = {'images' : keys}
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

def main():
    app = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [('/', MainPage),
        ], debug=True)
```

The above code uses the os library, but I thought you weren't allowed to us it in GAE.

My app.yaml file looks like:

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  script: image-getter.app

libraries:
```

The html, index.html file looks like:

```
<div>
{% for i in images %}
<img src="/getimage?key={{i}}" />
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I can't seem to get the app to run, I get "Error: Server Error," which isn't awfully helpful.

Thank!

Comment: Where is your `app` callable?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I'm not sure what you mean by that, sorry I'm a real beginner.

Comment: Naming python modules with a hyphen in them is a Bad Idea. Also, you need to read your applications logs and show us the traceback. The Server Error in the browser isn't meant to be helpful; the logs are.  Also, you seem to be learning from a very, very old tutorial. You should be using webapp2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no image-getter.app in your image-getter.py. Also there is no routing in your image-getter.py check example here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

You need to add something like

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

When you post code, please include the import statements, your code seems invalid because it does not import the db module.

Comment: I've updated my submission, could you take another look please. :) Thank you.

Comment: You do not need to put the app inside function main just put it at module level, see the example from the link I posted. The run_wsgi_app statement also not necessary.

Comment: K, I've removed those bits. I still get the same error. Any idea what's going on? Thanks

Comment: if you still put it inside a main function, there is no module level variable called app, remove the main function too, make the app a variable in module level.